Encontrar los números faltantes en un tabla en SQL Server
Tengo el siguiente código:
use [AMIGO UTS GNS]
DECLARE @MC INT;
SET @MC = 0; SELECT    P1.Id_Factura AS "No. Factura Inicial",
 P1.Fecha AS "Fecha Factura", @MC+1 AS "Cantidad Saltos"
FROM   [AMIGO UTS GNS].[dbo].[Facturas] P1
LEFT JOIN    [AMIGO UTS GNS].[dbo].[Facturas] P2
ON P1.Id_Factura = P2.Id_Factura - 1
WHERE  P2.Id_Factura IS NULL

que arroja la siguiente salida de los números que no tienen consecutivos:
No. Factura Inicial Fecha Factura   Cantidad Saltos
16962   2009-07-14 00:00:00.000 1
23087   2009-10-09 00:00:00.000 1
149561  2023-10-16 00:00:00.000 1
160088  2024-01-16 00:00:00.000 1
170178  2024-01-26 00:00:00.000 1
170593  2024-04-11 00:00:00.000 1
180926  2024-05-28 00:00:00.000 1
191221  2024-06-28 00:00:00.000 1
201400  2024-07-23 00:00:00.000 1
211414  2024-08-05 00:00:00.000 1
222803  2024-12-02 00:00:00.000 1

Pero necesito saber desde el número que no tiene consecutivos, cuáles faltan, por ejemplo:
1000,10001,1003,2000
¿Cuántos faltan? 997.

cuales el numero consecutivo al que te refieres? en todo caso la forma seria utilzando la funcion  LAG para restar el valor actual menos el anterior y listo!

Es decir debe saber cual es el numero que  no tiene consecutivos , y cual seria la cantidad que falta hasta el siguiente numero consecutivo.

puedes hacerlo utilizando la funcion LAG
ejemplo:
SELECT    P1.Id_Factura AS "No. Factura Inicial",
P1.Id_Factur - LAG(P1.Id_Factura, 1, P1.Id_Factura) OVER (ORDER BY P1.Id_Factura) AS diferencia,


Haría falta tomar esa consulta en un subquery o CTE para agregar WHERE diferencia > 1

Caballero agradecido, pero no se como seria cte, me colaboras. le modifique para que solo me muestre los intervalos  de las facturas en el conteo, y que me discrimine la factura existente antes y la factura existente al final.
